# Ajax call not hitting the controller action method, status 500 , Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

My ajax call to controller action method is not hitting the controller, it breaks in between. It says that `xhr.status = 500`, `response text = Internal Server Error`

The same code is working fine in other project.

**JavaScript Code**

```
 ajaxCall: function (data, url, success, error, noShow) {
    // make sure that there is never an empty POST body to protect against proxy allowing too soon
    if (!data) {
        data = "{'dummy':1}";
    }
    var reqData = data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        // switch on/off geenraic AJAX events bound globally
        /** @default false
        */
        global: !(noShow || false),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        // add CSRF token to each request
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { /* jquery 1.5.* use headers */
            var csrf_token = $("[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
            xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', csrf_token);
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            // repeat ajax call when "Empty body element" message gets returned. It means that proxy challenge was completed too soon.
            if (a.responseText == "EmptyBodyElement")
                Service.ajaxCall(reqData, url, success, error);
            else {
                if (error)
                    error(a, b, c);
                else
                    Service.responseError(a, b, c);
            }
        }
    });
},
```

I am receiving error in jQuery 1.9.1

```
if ( callback && ( isAbort || xhr.readyState === 4 ) )
```

`xhr.status = 500`, `xhr.responsetext = Internal Server Error`

The same code working in other projects, I have checked all the regrences are in place.

Answer (score 0):

The controller action method

[AllowAnonymous]

public ActionResult CheckUserStatus(string UserId, bool NewUserStatusCheck)

{

}

The breakpoint is not hitting

Xhr.responstext = "Internal Server Error"

Comment: anybody please help.. by doing research on this issue on different threads I came to know that issue is somewhere in .config .. somebody suggested to check the request and response in Fiddler but The request is not reaching to the server, and response is nothing..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Here is my Code with Error.

 JQUERY CODE

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "@Url.Action("AllocateByCapacity","BookScenario")",
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: JSON.stringify({'scenarioId':JSON.stringify(PlanningBookHandler.getScenarioId())                                     
                        }),
                        success: function (response) {
                            SCP.Utils.showMessageDialog("Records Updated");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            SCP.Utils.showMessageDialog("Records UpdateFailed");
                        }
                    });
```

CONTROLLER ACTION METHOD CODE

```
 public ActionResult AllocateByCapacity(int scenarioId)
 {

            return Json(new object());
 }
```

In My case, you can see I am passing the string value to action method which is expecting  an integer parameter. That's the error I found in my code. After changing parameter to integer value code worked fine.